# Is Fusion 360 compatible with SolidWorks?

Tags: solidworks, software

I.e. can I save a model in Fusion 360 that can then be opened in SolidWorks?

Answer (score 1):

You can export the geometry yes by exporting a STEP (or IGES file  which is slightly worse). But not much else, the object will be a black box as it has no construction history. Whether this counts as the model moved over is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I use Inventor, but 360 should allow you to export as a step file that you can import into solid works.